# ASP.NET GridView examples - Using code-behind - no wizards - no drag/drop

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I am looking to implement and learn more about the ASP.NET GridView control. However, all the examples I have found seem to focus on setting up a SQL Datasource within the ASPX page. I prefer to keep markup as seperate as possible from code and therefore all datasource binding I like to do in the code-behind. So it would be great to see an example that setup the GridView in that manner.

Also, most of the examples, I have seen, step through using the Visual Studio IDE and wizards to implement the GridView. I would like to see how it is done from a pure code point of view.

Does anyone have any examples or perhaps know of some resources that describes usage of the GridView control in the manner in which I described?

It would be great to see an example(s) that cover sorting, paging, and CRUD operations. Thanks for your time.

Comment: You say "controller". Do you mean "control"?

Comment: I suggest that you consider the difference between "markup" and "declarative coding that happens to use XML".  "`<asp:SqlDataSource/>`" is not "markup" in the sense that "`<div>`" is markup.

Comment: @John Saunders - I don't think I mentioned "controller" anywhere. If I did, I apologize. To clarify I am just talking about the GridView control. I am not saying that declarative coding is a bad thing, rather, I just prefer not to do it. For me, it is mixing markup and data. I prefer to manage data connections from the code behind. I feel that declarative coding makes the ASPX more confusing than it has to be, especially for designers.

Comment: @webworm: you said "I am looking to implement and learn more about the ASP.NET GridView controller." It's been edited since you wrote it.

Comment: That's why I didn't see it. Thank you.

Comment: @webworm: I would tend to hire designers who are smart enough to ignore things they don't understand...

Comment: @John - Thankfully .. I am not in charge of hiring anyone. The point I was trying to make is .. I prefer to handle the data-source from code-behind and am looking for such examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple example that includes sorting and paging. [Gridview Example](http://littletalk.wordpress.com/2009/02/11/gridview-with-datatable-as-source-with-paging-and-sorting/). Obviously you just need to plug in your call to your DAL and put the data in a DataTable. Though the example is simplistic, I think it conveys what is needed to get rolling.

Answer (score 1):

```
MyGrid grid = new MyGrid();
grid.DataSource = GetContents(); // call into your business or data layer
grid.DataBind();
```

Comment: I was looking for some complete examples of using the GridView (Add/Edit/Delete - Sorting - Paging)

Comment: Some good samples here: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Search/en-US?query=gridview%20examples%20for%20asp.net%202.0&ac=1

Answer (score -1):

```
///////////////////////THIS IS CHECK ONLY////////////

protected void restore_btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < GridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        GridViewRow row = GridView1.Rows[i];

        bool isChecked = ((CheckBox)row.FindControl("chekbox")).Checked;
        if (isChecked)
        {
    // Column 2 is the name column

    //str.Append(GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[2].Text);
  }
}

    //   foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView1)
//{
    //    for (int i = 0; i < GridView1.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
    //    {
    //    CheckBox check = (CheckBox)row.Cells[0].FindControl("chekbox");

    //    if (check.Checked)
    //    {
    //        //Take Row information from each column (Cell) and display it
    //    }
    //    else
    //    {
    //        //Display in seperate area
    //    }
    //}

        //string deletepatient;

        //for (int i = 0; i < GridView1.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
        //{
        //    //GridView1.SelectedRow.
        //    //if (GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0]. == true)
        //    //{
        //    //    deletepatient = deletepatient + "," + GridView1.Columns[i]["account_no"];
        //    //}
        //}

//        foreach(Gridviewrow gvr in Gridview1.Rows) 
//{ 
// if(((CheckBox)gvr.findcontrol("CheckBox1")).Checked == true) 
// { 
//   int uPrimaryid= gvr.cells["uPrimaryID"]; 
// } 
//} 

        //foreach (GridView1 gvr in GridView1.Rows)
        //{
        //    if (((CheckBox)gvr.findcontrol("checkbox1")).Checked == true)
        //    {
        //        int id = grv.cells["chekbox"];
        //    }
       //}

        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), "alert", "alert('Record 
Restore Successfully..');", true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you please improve your code formatting? It will make it easier to read what you've posted. Also I'm wondering why you've provided so much commented out code